# Xcode only shows iOS Provisioning Profiles. How to sign Mac Apps?

Tags: xcode, macos, provisioning-profile, mac-app-store

I am working on Apps for iOS and Mac App Store. Last time I worked on the Mac App Project was in last summer when I was still using Xcode 4.5 and Lion. Meanwhile I have updated to Mavericks and Xcode 5.0.2. Now I encounter the Problem, that I cannot compile the Mac App Project since the right Provisioning Profiles cannot be found.

While in Xcode 4.x the profiles have been managed in the Organizer the have been moved to "Preferences/Accounts/View Details..." in Xcode 5. Problem is, that now only iOS profiles are listed there. In the project under "Target/Build Settings/Code Signing" only iOS profiles are available as well.

How do get my Mac profiles back?

In the Mac/iOS Provisioning Portal all profiles are up to date. I tried to manually download the profiles and add them with a double click. However this works only for Development Profiles and for Store Profiles (System says they are managed directly by Xcode). After Adding the Development Profile manually it is still not available in Xcode.

Restarting Xcode or the system does not change anything.

Is this a known problem? Any advise how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: First check if your mac dev accnt hasnt expired (its not clear from the question). If you are still member then its better to create new PProfiles/certificates.